# Windows 7 not starting correctly on Toshiba Satellite L640

Tags: windows-7, windows, bsod, toshiba-laptop

I'm experiencing a problem with my Toshiba Satellite L640 running Windows 7.  I initially experienced a blue screen and the computer restarted itself.  When I attempted to reinstall Windows, the system seemed normal again.  But I'm getting "ERROR OPENING WINDOWS", and when I start the computer, it takes a very long time and either Windows will not start, or Windows will start with the classic theme and not all programs can be opened.  Why is this happening, and what can I do about it?

Comment: I'm sorry, but Stack Exchange is English only. [Non-English Question Policy](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/non-english-question-policy/)

Comment: Ran the content through Google Translate, source text was in Indonesian.  The output is reasonably intelligible, so I replaced the question body with the Google translation.

Comment: I took the effort to completely rewrite the post, so that the question is clearly understandable.

Comment: For the OP: Untuk menerjemahkan jawaban atas bahasa Anda, klik di sini: http://translate.google.com/#id|en| Salin jawaban ke dalam kotak teks.

Comment: You should probably consider buying a new Windows 10 laptop, that Toshiba with Windows 7 will soon no longer be supported by Microsoft/Toshiba.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like a video hardware problem, given that the classic theme is sometimes being used.  You may need to have the computer serviced by Toshiba if the graphics processor (GPU) is damaged.

---

*Machine translation from Google Translate / Mesin terjemahan dari Google Translate*

Ini terdengar seperti masalah perangkat keras video, mengingat bahwa tema klasik kadang-kadang digunakan. Anda mungkin harus memiliki komputer dilayani oleh Toshiba jika prosesor grafis (GPU) rusak.